# block dissemination in fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, gossip

I'm following [Gossip protocol](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gossip.html).

> For dissemination of new blocks, the **leader peer** on the channel pulls the data from the ordering service and initiates gossip dissemination to peers.

Is the leader peer only leader of its own organization or leader of all the peers?

If each organization has its own leader, will they pull new blocks from different Orderer Node whose ledger is different from one another? I mean OrdererLedger is different from one other with the SIGNATURES in block metadata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the leader peer only leader of its own organization or leader of
>   all the peers?

Only of its own organization

> If each organization has its own leader, will they pull new blocks
>   from different Orderer Node whose ledger is different from one
>   another? I mean OrdererLedger is different from one other with the
>   SIGNATURES in block metadata.

Yes that is correct. Each orderer has its own ledger but the order of the transactions (and the transactions themselves) are the same.
However - the signatures are not the same signatures (they are created by each orderer node).
Why is that a problem though?

Comment: Because I'm wondering whether I can copy the file ledger from one node to another one which is out of sync. I don't know what can I do if one of the orderer crashed and messages to consume in the kafka log had been deleted.@yacovm

Comment: Yes, you can copy the file ledgers from one orderer to another. Replace the `/var/hyperledger/production/orderer` directory on the out of sync order with a copy from an up-to-date orderer.